# False equations with Euler's Identity

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

What's wrong with the following equations?

$$1 = 1^{-i} = (e^{2πi})^{-i} = e^{-i2πi} = e^{2π}$$

My guess would be the third equation, but I can't really tell why... in the first equation, we use the fact that $1^z$ is still $1$ for any $Z \in C$; in the second step, we insert Euler's Identity... and in the last equation, we simply use $-i2πi = 2π$. But if I'm right with my suspicion, why is the third equation wrong? Can't we use the power rules for complex numbers?

Comment: Why is not $1=e^{0 i}$? Also $1=\cos 0+i\sin 0$.

Comment: I think $1^{-i}=1$. But, I am not sure

Comment: See the last answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838908/is-the-power-of-complex-number-defined-yet).

Comment: I guess that it is $1^i=1$. One just to be careful with complex functions. The above *equality* is of the same type as the following: $1=\sqrt{1}=\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}=\sqrt{-1}\cdot \sqrt{-1}=i\cdot i=-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that complex powers are multi-valued functions.  By definition, $a^b = e^{b \log(a)}$, but there are different branches of $\log(a)$, each of which may give a different value to $a^b$.  So it's not true in general that $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$.  What you can say is that
$(a^b)^c = \exp(c \log(a^b)) = \exp(c \log(e^{b \log a}))$, and 
$\log(e^{b \log a}) = b \log a + 2 \pi n i$ for some integer $n$, so
$$(a^b)^c = \exp(c(b \log a + 2 \pi  n i)) = a^{bc} \exp(2 \pi c n i)$$

The possible logarithms of $1$ are $2 \pi n i$ for integers $n$, so
$1^{-i} = \exp(-i \log(1)) = \exp(2 \pi n)$ where $n$ can be any integer.