# complex number raised to the power i?

Tags: complex-numbers

If you take a general complex number x+iy and raise it to the power i, what does this mean and what is the resulting value i.e. what are the real and imaginary parts? I need to apply this to z=-1-i

Comment: Maybe try $x + iy = r e^{i\theta}$ and move from there.

Comment: [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/838908/81360)

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexExponentiation.html

Comment: from the formula derived for a general complex number raised to a general complex power in the link, as arg(z) is multiplied by "c", if I have a complex number raised to pure imaginary number (c=0) the arg(z) will vanish...s there is no angular dependence?

Comment: Not sure I picked the best duplicate original, but this was highly voted anyway. A tip from a veteran: check the list of **Related** questions in the right margin. When asking a standard question you will more often than not find something that fits there!