# Finding the $i$th power of $i$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

I have been trying to find the $i$th power of $i$ as a mental exercise, I have tried two approaches

For the first, using properties of exponents

$$i^i=i^{\sqrt{-1}}=i^{-1^{\frac{1}{2}}} \implies i^i=i^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{i^2}=-1$$

However this seems a bit, for a lack of a better word "bodgy".

The next method I used was rewriting into exponential form

$$z=i^i + 0 \implies \arg(z)=\tan^-{1}\left(\frac{1^i}{0}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$ \therefore i^i=e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}$$

I am quite sure that none of these answers are correct, what are the flaws in my method and how should I go about actually computing this ?

Comment: You might like this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tlHQOKMHGA) on the subject

Comment: [See also this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/838908/81360) (not quite the same question but obviously related)

Comment: For both of your approaches, I do not understand the $\implies$ step. It would be helpful if you tried to explain your thought process there

Comment: You've conflated $a^{b^c}$ with $a^{bc}$, which doesn't even work with $a=b=2,\,c=3$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann For the first step I applied the exponent property $(x^a)^b=x^{ab}$ and for the next I used the property that $tan(z)=\frac{y}{x}$ and since the coefficient of the imaginary part is $1$ and 1 raised to any power is 1 I got the argument as $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: @Filthyscrub Thanks for clarifying. For the first step, as J.G. notes, 
$$
i^{(-1)^{1/2}} \neq [i^{-1}]^{1/2}.
$$
For the second, it's not clear where $1^i$ came from

Answer (score 3):

The typical approach to the problem is this:
$$
i = e^{\pi i /2} \implies
i^i = [e^{\pi i/2}]^i = e^{\pi i^2 /2} = e^{-\pi/2}.
$$
However, as I note in my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/838908/81360), this actually leads to several (infinitely many) possible values for $i^i$. Interestingly, each of these possibilities is a positive real number.

Answer (score 0):

Write

$$i^i = \left(e^{\log i}\right)^i = e^{i \log i}$$

and use the fact that

$$ \log w = \mathrm{ln}|w| + i \,\mathrm{arg}\,w$$

Note that $\mathrm{arg}\,w$ is a multivalued function.